# How to add JS code in the head tag for only in the success page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript

I need to add a JS script on the head tag, but only in the Success page. Inside Magento 2, I have no idea how doing this.

Someone can help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create the `checkout_onepage_success.xml` file at following location on your custom extension

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\checkout_onepage_success.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Extension::js/yourcustom.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

2. now create `yourcustom.js` on the following location

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\web\js\yourcustom.js

3. now in `yourcustom.js` added your code what ever you want to add.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create **checkout_onepage_success.xml** layout in your module then adds the below code inside the page tag

```
<head>
    <script src="Vendor_Module::js/custom.js"/>
</head>
```

After that, you can create custom.js file inside your custom module.